# where we can find higgs boson particle

Tags: higgs

This weeks greatest news is the discovery of higgs boson like particle. My question is where higgs boson is found; whether it is found in both matter and antimatter or it is found only in matter, if only in matter then there is any theoretical anti higgs boson like particle present in antimatter or not?

Answer (score 3):

This [125 GeV new particle](http://public.web.cern.ch/public/) is a neutral boson.Elementary  [neutral bosons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosons) are their own antiparticle, like the photon, the Z0 and now the Higgs.   Composite ones may be so too, depending on the quantum numbers that the quarks they are composed of carry. The pi0 for example is its own antiparticle, since quark-antiquark switch roles.

Answer (score 2):

> where we can find higgs boson particle

Evidently, at the LHC.  :)

The Higgs boson, as conceived in the Standard Model, is the observable quantum of 1 of the 4 degrees of freedom of the Higgs *field*.  Loosely speaking, the anti-particle of the Higgs is "eaten" by the Z boson and so is not observable (except as the mass of the Z).

Answer (score 1):

Higgs Boson is found everywhere in the universe (even where there is no matter). Its messenger particle of universe-wide Higgs field.

**What is Messenger Particle?**
Photon is messenger particle of electromagnetic field which defines the field (conditions of space). Higher field intensity means high density of photons. Similarly, gravitons are messenger particles of gravitational field. You can understand it as conveyor of gravitational force. Force/energy is exchanged with messenger particles.

Charge is determined by level of interaction with electromagnetic field. Similary, rest mass is determined by level of interaction with Higgs field. So, Higgs Boson gives something "Rest Mass" based on level of interaction with it. For example, photons don't interact with Higgs Boson at all, so photons don't have mass. Up Quarks interacts with it upto high extent, so they have high rest mass.

Comment: The Higgs is not the only source of mass. The proton gets most of its mass from QCD. Mass is not defined as the interacton with the Higgs, it is defined by its interaction with gravity. On the other hand, charge is defined by the interaction with the electromagnetic field. So gravity is the field for mass analogous to electromagnetism for charge. The Higgs just accidentally happens to be the mechanism by which chiral fermions get mass in the standard model, this is not a universal property of mass in an arbitrary theory, and it isn't where the proton gets its mass.

Comment: Also, the Higgs boson is not the same as the Higgs field, and the Higgs boson can only be found where it is made, pretty much at LHC, and perhaps in occasional cosmic ray collisions.

Comment: @Ron Gravity doesn't exist in SM. See this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31247/why-do-we-need-higgs-field-to-re-explain-mass-but-not-charge

Comment: @Ron Higgs Boson is found everywhere in the universe. Without it, you can't define Higgs Field.

Comment: Please stop trolling, this is ridiculous. The graviton is to mass as the photon is to charge. The Higgs is _not_. Gravity doesn't appear in the SM, so what? It's the right analog, the Higgs isn't the right analog. Your answer is wrong. The Higgs boson is not required to define the Higgs field, the Higgs field is the angular part, and in a nonlinear sigma-model Higgs, there is no Higgs boson, but the Higgs field is exactly the same. The Higgs field is the condensate, the Higgs boson is the neutral excitation of the leftover component after the Higgs field is absorbed into W's and Z's.