# The exact nature of electromagnetic charge

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

It is an assumed that positive and negative electromagnetic charges,"attract" each other. But what IS charge?

Comment: It is itself and not something else. We didn't give it a new name for nothing, after all.

Comment: Why the quotes? And why are you assuming things? Isn't this how you *define* charges?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109535/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

From what we can tell, charge is basically a property of matter that makes things be attracted and repelled from one another. Now what gives matter charge? the sub-atomic particles that make up atoms, electrons have a negative charge and protons have a positive charge(there are other particles but thats for another question or googling). I understand your frustration with this strangeness but this is really how the cookie crumbles in our universe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that asking what is charge is like asking what is voltage, mass, space or time.  We can talk about the properties it has, but as for what it is... that may not be answerable by us, because it’s a basic property.