# What exactly is charge and what does it have to do with anything?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, charge, definition

Often charge is defined as a measure of interaction with the electromagnetic field. However, electromagnetic field is often defined as a field produced by moving electrical charges, or relates to charges in some way or the other. Due to this circular definition, I am not able to understand what really is charge and its influence on electromagnetism, or any interaction.

So what exactly is charge and what does it have to do with electromagnetism, or any other interaction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is charge actually? How to define it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106605/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109535/2451 and links therein.